# How can I use a class in closure of parallel\Runtime::run()?

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I'm trying to create an instance of an outer class in a closure but I got an error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'TestClass' not found in /home/**my home**/test-parallel.php:12`.

L.12 is `$test = new TestClass();`

How can I instantiate this class in the closure?

Here is the whole source code.

```
<?php

use parallel\Runtime;

class TestClass {
    function testPrint() {
        echo "TestClass";
    }
}

$thread_func = function() {
    $test = new TestClass();
    $test->testPrint();
};

$r = new Runtime();
$r->run($thread_func);
$r->close();
```

Comment: Have you tried `new \TestClass()` in case it's a namespace issue.

Comment: Yes, but the error is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the code of your class in the Closure function with require_once (same if the code of your class is in the same file)